# Hotkeys for switching directly to open app?

Tags: keyboard

Instead of using cmd+tab to switch between open apps, is there a way to create hotkeys for selecting the running instance of emacs/firefox/whatever? (Preferably opening them if they aren't running.)

I do not mind using Karabiner. Answers using built-in OS X functions preferred to third party software which again are preferred to those using software that costs anything.

Comment: Have you searched this site for answers?

Comment: Googled, but that would return AD answers if they existed.

Comment: Use the search filed on this site for` app  hotkeys` there will be enough results to set you on the right path